# Jenkins: connection between docker container with jenkins master and docker container with jenkins slave

Tags: docker, jenkins

I run docker container with Jenkins master. I run docker container with Jenkins slave ([slave image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bibinwilson/jenkins-slave/)) and exposed port 8082:8080.

I created docker network to make containers see each other and it works (ping works).

I installed [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) on Jenkins master. I checked IP address of the slave container and tried to use it in the master's configuration, but master cannot connect to slave:
[image: jenkins error]

I think I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas what else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your docker daemon listening on your DockerURL and then try Testconnection

`sudo dockerd`

check `API listening on`

or provide your `certs` path to credential section.

certs path usually will be %userprofile%/.docker

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing `HttpHostConnectException` because you are using `tcp` in the `Docker URL` field. Use `http`. Check the configuration document [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin).

Comment: I tried, but then I get "Unsupported protocol scheme found: 'http://...'. Only 'tcp://' or 'unix://' supported." error.

Comment: @M.Stefanczuk yes docker plugin supported only tcp and unix type protocol

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Here is nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwomWpJ0m3g&t=1709s) about setting up master in docker container and slaves aslo in docker containers. It doesn't use Docker Plugin.